# Youtube API - How to hide video still shot in beginning

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [YouTube iFrame api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). I created a video player which loads 10 different YouTube videos. It will play the first video (video 1) then once that's finished (completed) it will hide the youtube video player for 7 minutes and then load the second video and just loop though 1-10 videos. Pretty simple.

#### The issue

The YouTube player itself flashes a thumbnail (preview still shot) of the video first before it plays the video - it's kinda annoying. I want to not have it show a still shot of the video and just have it go right into playing the video. Is this possible to hide?

I hope I explained that well enough to understand.

Thank you.

- Tim

#### Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>


<script>

    var videos = [
      '<?php echo $youtube1; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube2; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube3; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube4; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube5; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube6; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube7; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube8; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube9; ?>',
      '<?php echo $youtube10; ?>',
    ]


    // Start with a random video
    // var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);

    var index = 0;

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytapiplayer', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: '<?php echo $youtube1; ?>',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError': onPlayerError
          },

          playerVars: { 
           'controls': 0,
            // 'cc_load_policy': 1,
            // 'start' : 1,
           'rel' : 0,
           'showinfo' : 0,
          }

        });
    }



// Skip video spot if YouTube ID is invalid by user
    function onPlayerError(event){
       // console.log(event.data);
        document.getElementById("ytapiplayer").style.visibility = "hidden";
        setTimeout(youtubeTimer, 0);
         index += 1
            if(index < videos.length) { // If its not the last item on the list
                playNewVideo()
            } else {
                // Go back to the start
                index = 0;
                playNewVideo()
            }
      }


    // Autoplay Video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();

        // Fade-out music player
        audio_fade_out();
    }


    var $youtubeTimeSetting = $.cookie("youtube_time");
    // log.console($youtubeTimeSetting);


    // When a video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) { 

          // alert("YouTube video ended");
          document.getElementById("ytapiplayer").style.visibility = "hidden";

          // Fade out music player
          audio_fade_in();

          setTimeout(youtubeTimer, 4200);
          // setTimeout(youtubeTimer, $youtubeTimeSetting);

          // generate new random number
          // index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
          // playNewVideo();


          // After video is done playing.
          index += 1
          if(index < videos.length) { // If its not the last item on the list
              playNewVideo()
          } else {
              // Go back to the start
              index = 0;
              playNewVideo()
          }

        }
    }

    function youtubeTimer() {
      // Fade-out music player
      audio_fade_out();

      // alert("YouTube video ended");
      document.getElementById("ytapiplayer").style.visibility = "visible";

      player.loadVideoById(videos[index]);
      event.target.playVideo();
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. It's probably not the correct way and it's more of a "hack" I guess..

**I pushed the video player off the screen after the video is finished. (completed)**

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("ytapiplayer").style.marginLeft = "5000px";
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); // Hide scroll bars
}, 1000);
```

**The once the video plays again. Put back on the screen**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("ytapiplayer").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}, 1000);
```

The "**setTimeout**" will allow the thumbnail to load off the screen. It seriously just flashes for a second.